# Angular CLI not installing

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am using node version 6.4.1 one of the latest.

While installing Angular CLI i am getting this error

[image: HERE IS THE - Angular CLI ERROR]

I Have already forced clear cache. Help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I have added package.json file it is still showing this error

Comment: can you try `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`?

Comment: try npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: 6.4.1? latest? in what sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correct syntax:- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 1):

The command is

```
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest
```